# Error Qt: QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record

Tags: sql, qt

mi problema es que al ejecutar el siguiente código:

```
void MainWindow::on_loginButton_clicked() {
  QString userName = ui->userLineEdit->text();
  QString userPassword = ui->passwordLineEdit->text();

  QSqlQuery q;
  q.exec("SELECT name FROM users.name WHERE name = 'javier'");

  QString nombre = q.value(0).toString();
  qDebug() << nombre;
}
```

Me aparece el siguiente error al presionar el llamado `loginButton`:

```
QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record ""
```

Comment: Creo que tu query deberia ser "SELECT name FROM users WHERE name = 'javier'"

Comment: Al principio probé eso, pero creeme que es lo mismo, el problema para mi que no es el sql

Comment: Intenta añadir q.first() antes de acceder los datos, o sea despues de tu query.

Comment: Gracias, esa era la razón

Answer (score 1):

Tu programa tiene dos errores:

**La consulta es incorrecta**

Como te han comentado en los comentarios, debería ser:

```
"SELECT name FROM users WHERE name = 'javier'"
```

La sintaxis de `SELECT` es:

```
SELECT [COLUMNAS] FROM [TABLAS] WHERE [FILTROS]
```

Solo pueden existir nombres de columnas es los campos `[COLUMNAS]` y `[FILTROS]`.

**Iteración de consultas**

Una vez que has ejecutado la consulta tienes que moverte por los diferentes registros devueltos. Si te fijas en tu código, para acceder a los valores devueltos usas:

```
QString nombre = q.value(0).toString();
```

Donde `q` es la propia `QSqlQuery`, es decir, el objeto sobre el que has ejecutado la consulta... Entonces, si la consulta devuelve 3 registros... ¿Cómo podemos acceder a cada uno? No existe algo tipo `q.value([REGISTRO],[COLUMNA])`, así que... ¿cómo se hace?

En la respuesta que has borrado dices de usar `q.first()`... esa sería una solución muy a medida. Hay una más genérica que permite trabajar con tantos registros como te devuelva la aplicación y es mediante el método `next()`:

```
QSqlQuery q;

if(! q.exec("SELECT name FROM users.name WHERE name = 'javier'") )
{
  qDebug() << "Error en la consulta: "
           << q.lastError().text();

  return;
}

while( q.next() )
{
  QString nombre = q.value(0).toString();
  // ...
}
```

Si solo interesa un único registro se puede cambiar el `while` por un `if`... así consigues un código bastante homogéneo independiente de la cantidad de resultados obtenidos.

Por cierto, nota que es recomendable comprobar el valor de retorno de `exec`... no vaya a ser que la consulta no se haya podido ejecutar por alguna razón.